Use of square brackets in quotes introduced after colon
I am writing an academic document related to legal research, and have a doubt - Wherever I am quoting someone like this:

Mr. A of X Institute states as follows: "[t]he suggestion that the number of enrolments is too few couldn't be further from the truth"

I understand that square brackets are used whenever I am quoting something from the start of a sentence in the middle of my own sentences, but the doubt I have is, can the quote which comes after a colon as shown above be treated as being in the middle of a sentence?

Whether you capitalize a full sentence that follows a colon depends on the style guide.
For example, the Publication Manual of the American Psychological Association (APA) requires that you capitalize after a colon:

It’s been snowing for three days straight: The roads around here aren’t very safe for driving.

The Chicago Manual of Style (CMOS), on the other hand, recommends that the word following a colon should be capitalized only if there are two explanatory sentences following the colon:

Maggie wears a brimmed cap at all times: strong light often gives her a headache.
Maggie wears a brimmed cap at all times: Strong light often gives her a headache. She also likes the way it looks.

Your example is different, though, as the colon is followed by a quotation.
The CMOS states:

A quotation that follows a verb of saying (e.g., writes, says, states, exclaims) and is run in to your text is introduced with a comma and begins with a capital letter. If the first quoted word begins with a lowercase letter in your source, use a capital letter enclosed in square brackets to indicate that you’ve altered the source:

In A Room with a View E. M. Forster writes, "[C]hoose a place where you won’t do very much harm, and stand in it for all you are worth, facing the sunshine."


APA recommends the same:

To identify the speaker of a quotation before the quotation appears, put a comma after the speaking-related verb (said, replied, stated, wrote, etc.).

Koval, vanDellen, Fitzsimons, and Ranby (2015) stated, "Although many factors likely predict who is asked to do what (e.g., collegiality; cooking skills), the current research suggests that one robust predictor of being relied on is being high in self-control" (p. 763).



To present a quotation after a complete sentence (e.g., those ending in thus or as follows), put a colon after the introductory sentence and before the quotation marks. Start the quotation that follows with a capital letter if the quotation itself is a full sentence; start the quotation with a lowercase letter if it is a sentence fragment.

Although some people believe tasks are easier for individuals with high self-control, the research has indicated as follows: “Participants actually working on the task found it equally difficult and draining, regardless of their own self-control” (Koval et al., 2015, p. 763).


Unline CMOS, APA recommends to silently capitalize words at the beginnings of quotations:

Some changes can be made to direct quotations without alerting readers:
– The first letter of the first word in a quotation may be changed to an uppercase or a lowercase letter to fit the context of the sentence in which the quotation appears.


In my understanding, according to both CMOS and APA, your example should therefore read:

Mr. A of X Institute states, "The suggestion that the number of enrolments is too few couldn't be further from the truth."


Thanks for the response. If I use a colon in between, and start from a newline, will that be acceptable? Ex, "Mr. A of X Institute states that: (in new line) "[t]he suggestion that the number of enrolments is too few couldn't be further from the truth.""

@AmitSonik Only if the quotation is 40 words or longer. Then indent it as a blockquote.
